# Simple CUDA Kernel Not Getting Launched from an application

Tags: cuda

consider the following simple kernel -

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <cuda.h>

 __global__ void dummyKernel(int *a)
 {
     int tid = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

     if(tid == 0) {
         a[0] = 10;
         a[1] = 6;
     }
 }

 int main() 
 {
     cudaStream_t stream;
     cudaStreamCreate(&stream);

     dim3 grid (2, 1, 1);
     dim3 block (8, 32, 1);

     printf("BEFORE CALL\n");
     int *a, *houtput;
     a = (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
     houtput = (int *)calloc(2,sizeof(int));
     int *d_a;
     a[0] = 4;
     a[1] = 5;
     printf("Before Execution Value of array: %d %d\n",a[0], a[1]);
     cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_a, 2*sizeof(int) );
     cudaMemcpy( d_a, a, 2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     dummyKernel <<< grid, block, 0, stream >>> (d_a);
     cudaMemcpy( a, d_a, 2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     printf("Value of array: %d %d\n",a[0], a[1]);

     cudaStreamDestroy(stream);

     printf("AFTER CALL\n");
     return 0;
 }
```

In an independent execution (i.e., putting this in a separate .cu file and compiling and running), this kernel behaves as it should, i.e., printing "10 6" after the kernel execution.

But when I insert this kernel in an application that I'm working on, it doesn't seem to get launched (but there is no compile time or runtime error). The result printed after the kernel launch is same as what was printed before kernel launch, ie, "4 5" (unlike the independent execution).

Any pointers to where to start looking for a solution to this problem (one seems to be the Makefile for the application). (I've  tried destroying old CUDA context (and all old CUDA contexts), and creating a new one. I've also tried inserting this dummy kernel at several places in my application, and currently am settled on the earliest location where a CUDA kernel can be placed). As additional information, there are some cuBlas kernels in the application that I'm working on, and they are getting launched to the GPU, but this dummy kernel isn't. (I'm using CentOS 6.6, CUDA 5.0)

Comment: What do You mean by _"insert this kernel in an application"_?

Comment: I mean that I copy paste the definition of dummyKernel, and the code inside main function, at a suitable location [definition of dummyKernel not a part of any function and the code inside the main function (except the return statement) as part of some other function that is getting executed] in the application that I'm working on.

Comment: Can You post the code of the application that cotains the _"inserted"_ kernel code?

Comment: It's a very large application and it won't be possible to post the code for even the cuda module. It's related to enhancing the CUDA support for a language called Charm++. The files don't seem to be online either. I've inserted the dummyKernel in a file named cuda-hybrid-api.cu (in charm++) you can try searching for it, but the result might be negative.

Answer (score -2):

I think in your codes the `stream` is useless,you could delete it.And I advice you should `synchronize` after kernel computing.

When processing your huge application ,mabey you should add a small printf to show whether you have do the kernel calculation step.Or you should provide your total appllication(make it as a small model)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <cuda.h>

 __global__ void dummyKernel(int *a)
 {
 int tid = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
   printf("see coming\n");//added
  if(tid == 0) {
    a[0] = 10;
    a[1] = 6;
   }
 }
 int main() {

 dim3 grid (2, 1, 1);
 dim3 block (8, 32, 1);

 printf("BEFORE CALL\n");
 int *a, *houtput;
 a = (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
 houtput = (int *)calloc(2,sizeof(int));
 int *d_a;
 a[0] = 4;
 a[1] = 5;
 printf("Before Execution Value of array: %d %d\n",a[0], a[1]);
 cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_a, 2*sizeof(int) );
 cudaMemcpy( d_a, a, 2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 dummyKernel <<< grid, block>>> (d_a);
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();//added
 cudaMemcpy( a, d_a, 2*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
 printf("Value of array: %d %d\n",a[0], a[1]);

 printf("AFTER CALL\n");
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: kernel computing is asynchronous with cpu execution,without synchronize ,your memcpy d2h may fail(I means transfer none value)

Comment: Inserting synchronization didn't work (neither did removing streams). Also, inserting printf in the cuda kernel throws an error in my system.

Comment: The comment `without synchronize ,your memcpy d2h may fail`suggests something that is simply not true.  Yes, a kernel launch is asynchronous, but the subsequent `cudaMemcpy` operation is a blocking call.  It will wait for all previous CUDA activity to complete.  There is never a need (for correctness) to place a `cudaDeviceSynchronize` operation immediately prior to a `cudaMemcpy` operation.

Comment: @noviceprogrammer I'm so sorry for didn't help you with your problem